# How to organise repeated code lines from different tags in CSS?

Tags: css

Let's say that I wrote html file with a lot of objects in it, and this file is styles with one css file. In that css file I could have in some lines same code.

For example:

```
.header {
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.leftLayer {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

So, I have *margin-left: 10px;* twice repeated. If *.header* and *.leftLayer* are not one bellow the other in code and on the page screen, what is the best solution? Is it to write code like this or something else?

```
.header, .leftLayer {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.header {
    color: #fff;
}

.leftLayer {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

This is simple example, but I need universal solution which can be applied for many div-s that have some same css values.

Comment: It depends on whether you're always going to want them styled the same for the chosen style - if you want to change the header to 15px but leave leftlayer at 10, you need to rewrite your style declaration. I find that combining selectors is best when they are similar elements that will likely always have the same styles (over the long term, this is)

Comment: I am still learning, and many times I see that my code is untidy and I thought that if I connect some objects I am gonna get more cleaner code. It sounds good to me that I need to take care what should be changed in in the future. And yes, I always look to combine similar elements. Thank you for advice.

Comment: Some programmers use a technique wherein you create classes for specific style sets, so as well as having a descriptive class such as `.header` `.nav-item` etc, you might also add to them `.ml-sm` or `.ml-md` (margin-left small and margin-left medium) which could have different margin sizes for different use cases. Of course these could have multiple styles e.g. color, font-size & line-height. The only downside is the extra HTML markup changes that could be required

Comment: It is an awesome idea and I believe that it can be really usefull. I can even create some starting class (like virtual) and than other classes can inherit that class but only if it make sense globally. Actualy, you gave me really good problem for thought. For me, now it looks that downside in html is not that big, because I can write main class first  and than the others, so there is not much conflict between. I can even comment at the beginning what are this classes so that it doesn't seem strange. I will definitely try it, and for few days I'll tell you impressions. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe consider using SASS? This will allow you to create containers to call in code to save your writing the same thing over and over (DRY)